# How to Pass button click event from one page to another page button

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7

In my WP 7.1 App i have two page named "PAGE 1" ,"PAGE 2"and having two buttons where "BUTTON 1' in page 1 and "BUTTON 2" in Page 2.however i click BUTTON 1 from page 1 its  automatically  Clicks the button 2 in page 2.. is it possible?? please help me soon..

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unclear as to what your situation is - so I'm going to write answers for the scenarios I can imagine:

If the two pages are on the same view (i.e. two `PanoramaItem`s on one `Panorama`), both buttons are available from the code-behind (if you're not using `Command`s - that is). You can then do something like this in the event handlers:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do action for Button1_Click
    // ...
    // Then call the event handler for Button2
    Button2_Click(sender, e);
}
```

If there are two different pages (i.e. two different XAMLs), you would have to send some kind of parameter through the `NavigationService`. In `Button1View.xaml`:

```
// a flag remembering if the button has been clicked
private bool hasButton1BeenClicked = false;

// The event handler for Button1
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do action for Button1_Click
    // ...
    // Then set a flag that says it has been clicked

}

// This method puts on the flag if the button was clicked
private string PrepareAddressToButtonView2(string uriToButtonView2) 
{
    if( hasButton1BeenClicked )
    {
        uriToButtonView2 = uriToButtonView2 + "?button1clicked=true";
    }
    return uriToButtonView2;
}
```

When you arrive in your second view, you have to manually trigger the eventhandler for the second button - but only if button1 has been clicked on the previous view. In `Button2View.xaml`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if( NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("button1clicked") )
    {
        Button2_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

Another way to solve this would be to save the state of Button1 (in a static field somewhere), and then check this when page2 is navigated to.

Hoped this helped!